# Onclick Submit event preventing Jquery Validation on Prototype Framework

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

am trying to use jquery validatoin before the form submit on prototype framework, after a loads of am still not able to finish it. I have the following code.

```
<script>
jQuery(function (jQuery) {
jQuery('#edit_form').submit(function () {

    var valid = true;
    var errormsg = 'required!';
    var errorcn = 'error';

    jQuery('.' + errorcn, this).remove();

    jQuery('.required-entry', this).each(function () {
        var parent = jQuery(this).parent();
        if (jQuery(this).val() == '') {
            var msg = jQuery(this).attr('title');
            msg = (msg != '') ? msg : errormsg;
            jQuery('<span class="' + errorcn + '">' + msg + '</span>')
                .appendTo(parent)
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .click(function () {
                jQuery(this).remove();
            })
            valid = false;
        };
    });

        return valid;
    });
})
</script>
            <table id="testform">
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;font-family:segoeui"><input id="Desc2" name="Desc2" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"title="Required" /></td>
            <td class="mono" style="width:15%;"><input name="qta2" value="" class="qta required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
            <td style="width:15%;" class="mono"><input name="bpa2" value="" class="bpa required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;font-family:segoeui"><input id="Desc3" name="Desc3" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"title="Required" /></td>
            <td class="mono" style="width:15%;"><input id="qta3" name="qta3" value="" class="qta required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
            <td style="width:15%;" class="mono"><input id="bpa3" name="bpa3" value="" class="bpa required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;font-family:segoeui"><input id="Desc4" name="Desc4" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"title="Required" /></td>
            <td class="mono" style="width:15%;"><input id="qta4" name="qta4" value="" class="qta required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
            <td style="width:15%;" class="mono"><input id="bpa4" name="bpa4" value="" class="bpa required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
                        <div class="submit content-header">
                           <h3 class="icon-head head-products">Page Title</h3>
                           <p class="content-buttons form-buttons">
                                <button id="id_be" type="button" class="add" onclick="document.edit_form.submit();" style=""><span>Submit</span></button>       
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <form action="test.php?IID=1" method="post" id="edit_form" name="edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="hidden" id="editform" name="editform" value="1" >
                            <div style="display:none"></div>
                        </form>
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sammry/qBHLB/

The form just gets processed with out validating the required fields. Help please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the preventDefault() function:

```
$('#edit_form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //rest of your code
}
```

PS: you can use $ instead of jQuery for shorthand writing.

If this doesn't work, try setting an ID to your submit button and change the event to

```
$("#submitButtonID").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

     //Validation

     if(valid){
         $("#edit_form").submit();
     }
}
```

---

EDIT: Entire code snippet

```
<script>
jQuery(function (jQuery) {
jQuery('#id_be').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var valid = true;
    var errormsg = 'Please fill in all required fields!';

    jQuery('.errormessages').html('');

    jQuery.each(jQuery('input'), function () {
        var parent = jQuery(this).parent();
        if (jQuery(this).attr('title') == 'Required' && jQuery(this).val() == '') {

            jQuery(this).attr('background-color', '#FF0000');
            // This will colour the background of the required input field red to make it more obvious to the user.

            valid = false;
        };
    });

    if(valid){
        jQuery('#edit_form').submit();
    }else{
        jQuery('.errormessages').html('<p>' + errormsg + '</p>');
    };

});
})
</script>

       <form action="test.php?IID=1" method="post" id="edit_form" name="edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class='errormessages'></div>
            <table id="testform">
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;font-family:segoeui"><input id="Desc2" name="Desc2" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"title="Required" /></td>
            <td class="mono" style="width:15%;"><input name="qta2" value="" class="qta required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
            <td style="width:15%;" class="mono"><input name="bpa2" value="" class="bpa required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;font-family:segoeui"><input id="Desc3" name="Desc3" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"title="Required" /></td>
            <td class="mono" style="width:15%;"><input id="qta3" name="qta3" value="" class="qta required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
            <td style="width:15%;" class="mono"><input id="bpa3" name="bpa3" value="" class="bpa required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;font-family:segoeui"><input id="Desc4" name="Desc4" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"title="Required" /></td>
            <td class="mono" style="width:15%;"><input id="qta4" name="qta4" value="" class="qta required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
            <td style="width:15%;" class="mono"><input id="bpa4" name="bpa4" value="" class="bpa required-entry input-text" type="text" title="Required" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
                        <div class="submit content-header">
                           <h3 class="icon-head head-products">Page Title</h3>
                           <p class="content-buttons form-buttons">
                                <button id="id_be" type="button" class="add" style=""><span>Submit</span></button>       
                            </p>
                        </div>

                            <input type="hidden" id="editform" name="editform" value="1" >
                            <div style="display:none"></div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried both, form just getting processes still. I cant use $ as prototype does not allow to use, hence i use it with noconflict

Comment: Please remove the onclick="document.main_form.submit();" of your button and use the 2nd codeblock in my answer.

Comment: i tried again both ways, using jQuery and replacing with $... now form not being processed or also its not showing any validation alert.

Comment: Remove the "return valid;" part from your validation process. It's causing the function to exit.

Comment: I'm just reading your entire code and it seems there is a lot wrong. Your input fields are outside of your form element. They should be inside the form or else the input will not be seen by php (if you are sending it to php). The whole validation itself seems to be written wrong as well. I will update my answer above with a full code example.

Comment: in the coded example, php form is getting submitted without any issue